# easy way to change logger name for each logger instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I have a root logging class that I created, which I'd like to use for each micro-service function that I'm deploying.

Example output log: `[2023-01-01 13:46:26] - INFO - [utils.logger.<module>:5] - testaaaaa`
The logger is defined in `utils.logger` so that's why it's showing that in the log, hence `%(name)s`.

Instead of using the same root logger name which is set with `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, how can I get the same structure in dot notation where the logger is being instantiated and called?

Even if I have to modify my logger class to accept a `name` parameter when initializing the object, that is fine. But I like the dot notation because I will have files like `routes.users.functiona`, `routes.users.functionb`, `routes.database.functiona` and so on.

So I want to show which module the logging came from. Can't seem to follow how `logging` is capturing the path when using `__name__`.

Also if you have any suggestions about making the following more robust :)
Here is my class:

```
import typing
import logging


class GlobalLogger:

    MINIMUM_GLOBAL_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    GLOBAL_HANDLER = logging.StreamHandler()
    LOG_FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] - %(message)s"
    LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

    def __init__(self, level: typing.Union[int, str] = MINIMUM_GLOBAL_LEVEL):
        self.level = level
        self.logger = self._get_logger()
        self.log_format = self._log_formatter()
        self.GLOBAL_HANDLER.setFormatter(self.log_format)

    def _get_logger(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(self.level)
        logger.addHandler(self.GLOBAL_HANDLER)
        return logger

    def _log_formatter(self):
        return logging.Formatter(fmt=self.LOG_FORMAT, datefmt=self.LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the logging concept.

The variable `__name__` holds the name of Python package where this variable is used. I think in your case it will have the value where `class GlobalLogger` is defined. And it does not matter from where you will create instance of your class. => Check it with print command.

At the top of every of your Python module (`*.py`), initialize module logger simply by `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. In your access the logging methods via module variable `logger`.

The logging data are automatically propagated to the parent logger based on the dot notation. If you have module A.B.C, the data are propagated C -> B -> A.
The output handlers, formatting  can be defined for every logger or just for root logger e.g.: `A` or just (empty) `""`.

I usually have function InitLogging, where I get handle to the root logger and setup the output handlers. You do not need setup logging handlers in every module.

Conclusion:

- If you still want use your class, give name of your logger as named parameter into the `__init__`. When you create instance of your class use variable `__name__` during initialization.
- I think there is not needed to create so many specific logger classes. You can define the logger properties later.